# Check if a value exists between two array indexes in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP

```
$array = array(2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1);
```

and I want to check, if a value exists between index 3 to 7, both index inclusive.

I have a workaround in mind. I can copy the array from index 3 to 7 into another array and then check with `in_array()` but wondering if there is any direct approach.

Comment: Use in_array() with array_slice().... `if in_array($needle, array_slice(3, 7-3+1));`

Comment: I don't think there is a more direct approach, except for looping using a loop like `for (i = 3; i <= 7; i++)` and checking the value at that index. Now `in_array` is probably more optimized, but still the overhead of copying a part would probably tilt the benefit towards the for loop. At the very least the loop is more memory-efficient.

Comment: @Mark Baker can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [in_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) with [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)....

```
$startPos = 3;
$endPos = 7;
if in_array($needle, array_slice($array, $startPos, $endPos - $startPos + 1)) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply go through the indeces 3 to 7 with a `for` loop:

```
$array = array(2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1); // your array
$min = 3;                                     // lowest index (inclusive)
$max = 7;                                     // highest index (inclusive)
$search = 3;                                  // value to look for
$found = false;                               // will be set to true if found
for($i = $min; i < $max; $i++) {
    if($array[$i] == $search) {
        $found = true;
    }
}
```

Like @MarkBaker said in his comment to your question, there are shorter ways to do it, but this is the most simplest and direct (IMO) method.

Comment: It is a good simple way but Mark Baker's comment is what I was looking for.